# Can not trigger click event using Jquery and PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I need one help.I need to trigger one click event which has applied to a button but it can not happen like that i am explaining my code below.

```
<div style="width:24%; float:left; padding:10px;">No of questions : 
 <input name="no_of_question" id="ques" class="form-control" placeholder="no of question" value="<?php if($_REQUEST['edit']) { echo $getcustomerobj->no_of_question; } else { echo $_REQUEST['no_of_question']; } ?>" type="text" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)">
<?php
 if($id!='' && $_REQUEST['edit']==1){
 echo " <script type=\"text/javascript\"> $('#plus').click(\"".$id."\") </script> ";
                                                       }
                                                    ?>
<div id="err_msg_name" style="font-size:12px; color:#FF0000; text-align: center;"></div>
 </div>
<div class="clear"></div>
 <div style="padding-bottom:10px;">
Questions : <input type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" name="plus" id="plus" value="+" onClick="addQuestionField();"><input type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" name="minus" id="minus" value="-" onClick="deleteQuestionField();">
</div>
```

my java script function is given below.

```
<script>
function addQuestionField(id){
    console.log('ids',id);
    var get =$("#ques").val();
    if(get==null || get==''){
        alert('Please add no of questions');
    }else{
        var counter = 0;
        if (counter > 0){
            return;
        }else{
             counter++;
              <?php
                   $status=array("status"=>'1');
                   $feeddata=$db->kf_answertype->find($ustatus); 
            ?>
            <?php
                 $status=array("status"=>'1');
                $feeddatascale=$db->kf_scale->find($ustatus);
            ?>
             for(var i=1;i<get;i++){

                  $('#container').append('<div><div style="width:24%; float:left; padding:10px;"> <textarea class="form-control" name="questions'+ i +'" id="questions" placeholder="Questions"  style="background:#FFFFFF;"  rows="2"><?php if($_REQUEST['edit']) { echo $getcustomerobj->questions; } else { echo $_REQUEST['questions']; } ?></textarea></div><div style="float:left;margin-top:37px;"><div style="float:left; margin-right:10px;"><?php foreach($feeddata as $v){?> <input type="radio" name="answer_type'+i+'" id="answer_type0" onClick="selectScale(this.value,'+i+');" value="<?php echo $v['_id']; ?>"> <?php echo $v['answertype']; ?> <?php }?></div><div style="float:left; margin-top:-10px;display:none;" id="scaleid'+i+'"><select class="form-control" id="nscale'+i+'" name="noofscale'+i+'"><option value="">Select Answer Type</option><?php foreach($feeddatascale as $v){ ?><option value="<?php echo $v['_id']; ?>" <?php if($getcustomerobj->no_of_scale == $v['_id'] or $_REQUEST['no_of_scale'] == $v['_id']){ print 'selected'; } ?>><?php echo $v['noofscale']; ?></option><?php } ?></select></div><div style="clear:both;"></div></div><div style="clear:both;"></div></div>');

             }

        }
    }
}
</script>
```

I need when that `if` condition will true the below function should called but its not happening like that.Please help me.

Comment: You can't combine js and php code in such manner. You should create ajax request to backend to run your php code, get result and process it into your js code

Comment: @alexander.polomodov : can you extract solution for this?

Comment: The parameter is not good, if you give a parameter (   $('#plus').click(XXX) ) that means you define the handler, to call the click you should only call  $('#plus').click()  with nothing in it (think about it as if you click on a button, you just click, you give no parameters)

Comment: No,Still issue is same.

Comment: Do you mind posting the resulting html page after php rendering ?